# Redux - Use action object method in reducer instead of switch

Tags: redux, reducers

I'm new to redux and looked at redux-actions or using switch statements in reducer, and though I'm not against using a switch statement, I'm wondering, isn't it easier to just use the call the action method?

Here's what I'm thinking

```
import actions from './actions'

const reducer = (state = {}, action) => {
   if (actions[action.type]) return Object.assign({},
       state, actions[action.type](action)
   );
   return state;
}
```

I've just tested this on my first reducer and action, and it works, but it seems quite obvious so I'm wondering why the switch type is the chosen way?

Comment: 1. Your action should take the existing state object as an argument right? 2. The switch case is just a stylistic decision. You can do anything as long as your reducer function returns a new state object. Whatever feels neater/cleaner to you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some observations:

1. Don't refer to these external functions as "actions". They're not actions. They're actually reducers themselves.
2. Being reducers, you really ought to be passing the state object to them. Oftentimes, you'll want/need to utilise information contained in the current state, as well as information contained in the action object.

Otherwise, this seems like an appropriate approach.

Comment: The difference between `switch` and an object (hash) with functions is negligible. However, the `Object.assign` locks the state shape down to an object and doesn't allow deletions. It just won't do for a general solution.

Comment: That's true. But I always keep the state shape consistent anyway. It would be problematic for the rest of my app if reducers were changing the state shape arbitrarily.

Comment: Sometimes an array is just more appropriate than an object.

Comment: Good point @DDS, I wrote a small function that lets me define what to delete from the new object, which kinda gets around that issue. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @pedalpete The reason most developers write reducers the way they do is because it's better. Don't make [hammer factory factories](http://discuss.joelonsoftware.com/?joel.3.219431.12).

Answer (score 3):

Switch statements are certainly the most common approach, but lookup tables are common as well.  You can even use plain if/then conditions if you want.  Ultimately, how you write your reducers is up to you.

FYI, this topic is covered in the [Redux FAQ](http://redux.js.org/docs/FAQ.html), in the [FAQ: Reducers](http://redux.js.org/docs/faq/Reducers.html#reducers-use-switch) section.  You might also want to read the new ["Structuring Reducers"](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/StructuringReducers.html) how-to section as well.